# background bug in IE8 when css box shadow is applied

Tags: internet-explorer-8, filter, css

I've created a DIV with background image and have applied box shadow effect around it. However in IE8 the shadow is appearing on the content within the DIV instead of the DIV itself.

This bug only happens when there's a background on the DIV, if there was no background, the box is fine.

Heres my example build:
http://jsfiddle.net/C9V2N/2/

Comment: It actually happens with `background-image` - if you apply a `background-color` it works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split the properties it seems IE isn't interpreting the same way than Chrome or FF like this:

```
#test {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x100');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C9V2N/21/

Hope it helps.

Aymeric.